# What is the strength of the second-order statement 'an uncountable closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point'?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

Perhaps surprisingly, we work in the language of second-order arithmetic.  I was wondering if the strength of the following statement LP was known:

*An uncountable closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point*.

For reference, the perfect set theorem (equivalent to ATR$_0$) implies LP, while LP implies ACA$_0$ (using Specker sequences).  Hence we have

ATR$_0 \rightarrow$ LP $\rightarrow$ ACA$_0$.

Do any of these reverse?

Comment: Isn't this just "Every tree either has a listing of its paths or has a non-isolated path"? I think it's easier to see the equivalence with $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it follows from ACA$_0$.  The point is that since you're not trying to prove the full perfect set property, you only need one iteration of the Cantor-Bendixson derivative.

Given a closed set $C$, two or three jumps can obtain the derivative $C'$.  If this is empty, then you can index the elements of C by basic open neighborhoods, and some finite number of jumps can turn this into whatever sort of countable listing you desire.  Otherwise, one more jump can find an element of $C'$, and then a sequence in $C$ converging to it.